# Trying to move buttons by holding mouse button and dragging

Tags: c#, button

I'm trying to develop my applications to create buttons like so:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int top = 150;
        int left = 150;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Left = left;
            button.Top = top;
            this.Controls.Add(button);
            top += button.Height + 2;
        }
    }
```

This is working how I intend, to an extent. I want to be able to create these buttons with certain properties, but I don't know how to access individual buttons.

Now, I also want to be able to move these buttons by holding down the mouse button and dragging them, then releasing them where I want. Here's what I've got from certain online resources and whatnot.

```
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.MouseDown += button1_MouseDown;
        }

        private Point MouseDownLocation;

        private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            }
        }

        private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                button1.Left = e.X + button1.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
                button1.Top = e.Y + button1.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have access to individual buttons you can try to make global list:

```
List<button> buttons = new List<button>();
```

And add them in for like:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Left = left;
button.Top = top;
this.Controls.Add(button);
top += button.Height + 2;
buttons.add(button);
```

Next, looking at function `button1_MouseMove` - it works only if mouse cursor is inside the button? Should it work like this?

If button is clicked you can look at the list to find which button is clicked and move it - your method looks ok.